# JSON encode accented charters for mirrorapi

Tags: json, encode, google-glass, google-mirror-api, non-ascii-characters

I send a message with the mirror api from an android app, but when I receive the timeline on my glass I can't see the accented charters like "è"

This is the string:

```
String text_message = "try this accented char è";
```

This is the creation of the JSON :

```
                String html_message = String.format(
                        "<article>" +
                                "<section>" +
                                "<div class=text-x-small>" +
                                "<p class=blue>%s" +
                                "<p>%s</p>" +
                                "</p></div>" +
                                "</section>" +
                                "<footer>" +
                                "<div>%s</div>" +
                                "</footer>" +
                                "</article>"
                        ,name,text_message,app_name);

                JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
                notification.put("level", "DEFAULT"); // Play a chime

                JSONArray menuitems = new JSONArray();

                JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
                reqObj.put("action","TOGGLE_PINNED");
                menuitems.put(reqObj);

                reqObj = new JSONObject();
                reqObj.put( "action", "READ_ALOUD" );
                menuitems.put( reqObj );

                reqObj = new JSONObject();
                reqObj.put( "action", "VOICE_CALL" );
                menuitems.put( reqObj );
                reqObj = new JSONObject();
                reqObj.put( "action", "DELETE" );
                menuitems.put( reqObj );

                json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("html", html_message);
                json.put("speakableText",message);
                json.put("menuItems",menuitems);
                json.put("notification", notification);

                MyLog.log("JSON TO SEND: " + json.toString());

                new sendJSON().execute();
```

This is the AsyncTask that send the JSON to the mirror api :

```
private class sendJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            postData();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //MyLog.log("Richiesta al server inviata GET CONTACTS");
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData() throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        HttpParams params_ = new BasicHttpParams();
        params_.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params_, "utf-8");

        String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/";
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params_);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost();
        httppost.setURI(new URI(BASE_URL + "timeline"));
        httppost.addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", mAuthToken));
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));

        try {

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            MyLog.log("RESPONSE: " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the response:

```
RESPONSE: {
"kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
"id": "ea3f9046-c0a2-4ed5-8a02-f6432f1XXX43",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/ea3f9046-c0a2-4ed5-8a02-f6432f1XXX43",
"created": "2013-12-22T20:28:37.278Z",
"updated": "2013-12-22T20:28:37.278Z",
"etag": "1387744117278",
"html": "\u003carticle\u003e\u003csection\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text-x-small\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"blue\"\u003e21:28\u003csub\u003e PM\u003c/sub\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp class=\"yellow\"\u003eMatteo Valenza\u003cp\u003eTry this accented char   \u003c/p\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/section\u003e\u003cfooter\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eWhatsGlass\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/footer\u003e\u003c/article\u003e",
"speakableText": "try this accented char  ",
"menuItems": [
{
"action": "READ_ALOUD"
},
{
"action": "DELETE"
}
],
"notification": {
"level": "DEFAULT"
}
}
```

**Why i don't see the accented char? How can I encode it in the correct way?**

Comment: JSON is encoded as UTF8.  If the original characters were UTF-whatever then they will pass through fine.  (If they were some other code page then you first need to translate to UTF before encoding as JSON.)  If properly encoded JSON does not display the characters correctly it's likely because the debug dump facility you're using does not handle "exotic" characters very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved !

escape the string to html :)

```
message = Html.escapeHtml(message);
```